# Presumed incompatibility between pgfplots-TikZ and pdflscape: externalization fails on all images

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-external, pdflscape

I'm trying to figure out why the externalization of tikzpictures does not work any more (used to).

I have the following in the preamble:

```
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
% \tikzexternalize[prefix=fig/ext/]
```

If I uncomment the second (to externalize all the plots and figures) line *all* the figures fail the externalization.

If the line is commented out (no externalization), the final pdf is generated without errors.

Unfortunately, I cannot recognize useful elements in the externalized log files.

Which is the best way to troubleshoot this? I suspect packages incompatibilities.

<s>Can't post a MWE right away (will write one as soon as I am able to),</s>

Here's a not-so-minimal *non* WE, reproducing the behavior described above:

```
\RequirePackage[hyphens]{url}
\RequirePackage[final]{graphicx}
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,openright,final]{memoir}
\usepackage{filecontents,lipsum}

\begin{filecontents*}{packages.tex}
    \usepackage{calc}
    \usepackage{ifoddpage}
    \usepackage[osf]{mathpazo}
    \linespread{1.1}
    \usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
    \usepackage{courier}
    \normalfont

    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[italian,english]{babel}
    \usepackage[obeyFinal]{todonotes}

    \usepackage{pgfplots,tikzscale}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{units}
    \usetikzlibrary{plotmarks,positioning,chains,fit,shapes,calc}

    \usepackage{array,booktabs,tabularx}
    \usepackage{mdframed,colortbl}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{pdflscape,rotating}

    \usepackage[shortcuts,noredefwarn,toc,symbols,acronym,nonumberlist]{glossaries}

    \usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,bm,bigints}
    \usepackage{dsfont}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage{xspace}
    \usepackage{csquotes}
    \usepackage{soul}

    \usepackage[vlined,ruled,commentsnumbered,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
    \usepackage[%
        bibstyle     = ieee,
        citestyle    = numeric,
        isbn         = true,
        doi          = false,
        sorting      = nty,
        % sorting     = none,
        % sorting     = debug,
        url          = false,
        defernumbers = true,
        bibencoding  = utf8,
        backend      = biber
    ]{biblatex}

    % % do not externalize todonotes' graphics
    \usepackage{letltxmacro} % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/115095/177

    \LetLtxMacro{\oldmissingfigure}{\missingfigure}
    \renewcommand{\missingfigure}[2][]{\tikzexternaldisable\oldmissingfigure[{#1}]{#2}\tikzexternalenable}
    \LetLtxMacro{\oldtodo}{\todo}
    \renewcommand{\todo}[2][]{\tikzexternaldisable\oldtodo[#1]{#2}\tikzexternalenable}

    \usepackage[pdfusetitle,final]{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{
        % bookmarksopen=true
        hidelinks,
        % colorlinks,
        pdfinfo={
            % Author={Alessandro Cuttin},
            Subject={PhD Thesis},
            % Title={Title to be defined},
       }
    }

    \usepackage[open,openlevel=1]{bookmark}
    \usepackage[noabbrev,capitalise]{cleveref}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{other-commands.tex}
    \hyphenation{a-chieved mil-li-me-ter-wave na-no-sat-el-lite}
    \newcommand{\Rho}{\textrm{P}}
    \newcommand{\matlab}{Matlab\textsuperscript\textregistered\xspace}
    \newcommand{\logand}{$\wedge$\xspace}
    \newcommand{\logor}{$\vee$\xspace}
    \newcolumntype{m}{>{$}c <{$}}
    % adapted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36003/177
    \usepackage{ifmtarg}% http://ctan.org/pkg/ifmtarg
    \makeatletter
    \newcommand{\algtoprule}{\hrule height.8pt depth0pt \kern2pt} % Caption top horizontal rule+skip
    \newcommand{\algmidrule}{\kern2pt\hrule\kern2pt} % Caption bottom (or mid) horizontal rule+skip
    \newcommand{\algbottomrule}{\kern2pt\hrule\relax}% Algorithm bottom rule
    \newcommand{\algcaption}[2][]{%
      \refstepcounter{algorithm}%
      \@ifmtarg{#1}
        {\addcontentsline{loa}{figure}{\protect\numberline{\thealgorithm}{\ignorespaces #2}}}
        {\addcontentsline{loa}{figure}{\protect\numberline{\thealgorithm}{\ignorespaces #1}}}%
      \algtoprule
      \textbf{\fname@algorithm~\thealgorithm}\ #2\par % Caption
      \algmidrule
    }
    \makeatother
    % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68310/177 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10131/177
    \makeatletter
    % \let\runauthor\@author
    \let\runtitle\@title
    \makeatother
    \DeclareMathOperator\erf{erf}
    \DeclareMathOperator\erfc{erfc}
    \newtheorem{theorem}{Proposition}
    \newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{lit-rev.tex}
    \chapter{Modern random access methods}
    \label{sec:mod-ran-acc-met}
    \lipsum
    \begin{figure}[tb]
        \centering
        \subbottom[ \label{fig:aloha-max-thr}]{%
            \includegraphics[width=0.475\textwidth]{aloha-throughput.tikz}
        }
        \caption{The Aloha System: \subcaptionref{fig:aloha-pac-sch} schematic of the Aloha communication multiplexing \cite{Abramson1970}, and \subcaptionref{fig:aloha-max-thr} network throughput.}
        \label{fig:lit-rev-alo}
    \end{figure}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{aloha-throughput.tikz}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
                ymax = 0.2,
                ymin = 0,
                xmin = 0,
                xmax = 2,
                xlabel={$G$},
                ylabel={$S$},
                ytick distance = 0.1,
                grid                            = major
            ]
            % throughput upper bound of Aloha
            \addplot [
                domain=0:2,
                samples=40,
            ]
            {x * exp(-2*x};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents*}
\input{packages}
\input{other-commands}
% \input{set/tufte-like-plots}

% toggle the following lines to prevent tikz plots compilation every time - always use after loading pgfplots package
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

% memoir settings
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}
\settocdepth{subsection}
\newsubfloat{figure}% Create subfloat in figure environment

\author{myname}
\title{mytitle}

\loadglsentries{example-glossaries-brief.tex}
\makeglossaries
\glstoctrue

\ifdraftdoc
% special things for a draft document
    \usepackage{showkeys}
    \linespread{1.3}        % more linespread for showkeys
    \makeevenfoot{simple}{}{\texttt{Draft: \today}}{ }
    \makeoddfoot{simple}{}{\texttt{Draft: \today}}{}
    % \usepackage{showframe}
\else
% perhaps special things for a non-draft document
\fi

% \includeonly{con/annotations,con/lit-rev,con/introduction,con/jsac}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{simple}
\frontmatter
\cleardoublepage
\tableofcontents
\glsunsetall
\cleardoublepage
\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage
\listoftables
\printglossaries
\glsresetall
\mainmatter
\part{Background}
\include{lit-rev}
\end{document}
```

It seems that externalized figures are not created.
I suspect a package incompatibility, and will try to comment out the packages one by one.

Comment: It shouldn't be hard to make an MNWE if any figure at all causes the failure. What error do you get? I.e. exact message? This will direct you to a per-figure log file. What does that log say? Did you remember shell-escape? Does the appropriate directory hierarchy exist?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @HenriMenke I can't make a MNWE _right away_, will do it asap. I know that without a M(N)WE it is harder to figure out an answer

Comment: @cfr I posted the error I get in the first per-figure log file. Shell escape is ok, and directories are in place

Comment: @AlessandroCuttin Then why did you post a question when you don't even know what to ask?

Comment: @HenriMenke Are you going to answer the question ?

Comment: hi @HenriMenke, let me explain: according to Murphy's Law, the externalization stopped working very close to the document's delivery deadline. That's why I cannot provide you guys with a MWE right now.
Anyway, I asked for direction on how to troubleshoot this. Seems a reasonable question, to me

Comment: @percusse “my code doesn't work” is not a question.

Comment: @AlessandroCuttin How to troubleshoot LaTeX: (1) Create a MWE.

Comment: @HenriMenke You are not the judge of that. If you are not going to answer the question don't engage and possibly annoy people with unnecessary policing.

Comment: @AlessandroCuttin You need to take your `\end{document}` and place it randomly in your document. If compiles move it further, otherwise move it up until you find where it chokes. Get that bit and make an example out of it. You will probably solve it before you bring it over here.

Comment: @percusse I'd love to answer but can't without a MWE.

Comment: thanks @percusse, it will probably happen as you say. Or I'll probably revert to a working version, and we'll never know.
Anyway, I don't want to cause unnecessary arguments. If I still can't figure out what's going on in a while, I'll delete the question myself

Comment: this may be related, though https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57434/177

Comment: You asked what is the best way to troubleshoot. Well in my opinion the most important this is no to waste too much time with random searches and speculation. You can google for 30 minutes hoping to find the red button but then you should stop and switch to a systematic debugging. And the first step of systematic debugging in tex is creating an mwe. Beside this I agree with Henri that your question as it is can't be answered, the `Runaway argument?` is certainly a problem and should be corrected but it is unclear if is also the source of your other problem.

Comment: Each externalized image receives its own .log file. Do these log files exist? They contain the clue on why the externalization failed. If there are no such log files, you have to open your main `.log` file and search for any related warnings. Perhaps the `-shell-escape` feature is disabled or disallowed the operation.

Comment: added a MNWE; I double-checked my editor (sublime text), and `-shell-escape` is enabled in the settings:     `"build_arguments": ["-shell-escape"],`

Comment: I found the same issue on another question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114764/calc-and-settocdepth-break-tikzexternalize
Even though a lot of effort was put in answering this question (thanks @UlrikeFischer) I found that the incompatibility of `\tikzexternalize` with the `calc` package and/or the `\settocdepth` command was the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not a pgfplots problem and also not directly cause by pdflscape. Imho it is a problem of `tikzscale`.

`tikzexternalshared.code.tex` calls at the end in `\AtBeginDocument` (after tikzscale has added all its code) if it detects pdflscape this here:

```
\tikzset{
            external/.cd,
            optimize command away=\landscape,
            optimize command away=\endlandscape
        }%
```

The problem is that this code not only adds the new commands to the internal code of `optimize command away` but also reapplies older code and as \includegraphics is in the list it breaks.

This document reproduce the problem (\jobname-figure0.pdf shouldn't exist):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{testinput.tikz}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents*}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\usepackage{tikzscale}


%breaks:
\AtBeginDocument{
        \tikzset{%           
           external/optimize command away=\blub,
        }%
        }%      

%  work around, uncomment to avoid the error:
% \tikzset{%
%         external/optimize/install/.code={},
%         }

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=0.475\textwidth]{testinput.tikz}

\end{document}
```

A work around is to disable the optimization or at least to remove `\includegraphics` from the list.

Comment: it is probably like you say, because I'm again at the starting point, even if removing `pdflanscape` seemed to work at first.
How do I disable the optimization?

Comment: My example shows a work-around.

Comment: I tried it, but didn't work :(

Answer (score 2):

Comment out `\usepackage{pdflscape}`.  Sorry, I don't have an explanation.

Comment: Thanks! No explanation needed ;) Maybe it could be helpful to report this presumed incompatibility to @Christian Feuersänger
I'll take care of it

Comment: it has been reported on the `pgfplots` support page
https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/support-requests/18/